# Querydsl Contains Column value in a String

Tags: java, querydsl, predicatebuilder

Generally we can use QObject.column.in(String[])  to find rows that specific column value in a string list. But how can we filter if column value exists in a large string?

Something like QObject.column.in(String)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> containsIgnoreCase

http://querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.3/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/types/dsl/StringExpression.html#containsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-

```
public BooleanExpression containsIgnoreCase(String str)

Create a this.containsIgnoreCase(str) expression

Returns true if the given String is contained, compare case insensitively

Parameters:
    str - string
Returns:
    this.containsIgnoreCase(str)
```

**Example:**

`QObject.column.containsIgnoreCase(yourString)`